# C# Generics - Can I make this class into a generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class repeated many times. My boss ask me to make to generic but I'm not sure what this means. Can anyone out help or suggest how? Sorry for bad English. I hope it make sense.

```
public class CapacityServiceContext : TableServiceContext
{
    public CapacityServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }
    public const string TableName = "Capacity";
    public IQueryable<Capacity> CapacityTable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<Capacity>(TableName);
        }
    }

}
```

thank you in advance.

Mina

Comment: Can you post more examples of this class? Is it always the same?

Comment: You should probably ask your boss what he/she meant

Comment: Go look up what a List<Type t> is exactly.  This will given you an idea of how a Generic collection works.  You need to ask your boss what he wants exactly.  If you don't understand what a Generic is then you should ask for assistance.

Answer (score 7):

As an example, your code could probably look like this:

```
public class ServiceContext<T> : TableServiceContext
{
    public ServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }
    public const string TableName = typeof(T).Name;
    public IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<T>(TableName);
        }
    }
}
```

And would be instantiated like any generic class:

```
ServiceContext<Capacity> context = new ServiceContext<Capacity>(…);
```

Essentially, I have changed every occurrence of `Capacity` in your class into `T` and made the class generic by appending `<T>` to the class name. Now the class is usable for other types as well.

Comment: I think you mean, you changed every occurrence of `Capacity` to `T`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Seems to work so far. The only change I had to make was this:  

 public static string TableName = typeof(T).Name;

Answer (score 3):

You can make `TableServiceContext<T>`, but your problem is going to be with your TableName constant. Unless you can guarantee that the table name is always the same name as the class of your generic, then it doesn't look good.

But if you can make that guarantee, it would look something like this:

```
public class TableServiceContext<T>
{
    public TableServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }
    public string TableName { get { return typeof(T).Name; } }
    public IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<T>(TableName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics are very popular and can help make your code more reusable.

Here is a general overview, you can decide how to best use it in your projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would gues your boss wants something like the following:

```
public class ServiceContext<T> : TableServiceContext
{
    public ServiceContext(string baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseAddress, credentials)
    {
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name);
        }
    }

}
```

You should ask him/her to be sure though, you'd use this class as follows:

```
ServiceContext<Capacity> serviceContext = new ServiceContext<Capacity>();
IQueryable<Capacity> query = serviceContext.Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming he is suggesting that you make it generic with regard to Capacity.

```
public class ServiceContext<T> : TableServiceContext {

...

public IQueryable<T> Table {        
  get {            
    return this.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name);       
  }    
}
```

Then you could create a:

```
ServiceContext<Capacity>()
```

Without seeing the other classes, I'm not sure what would really be involved.

Comment: Hello. All my classes are the same. The only thing different is that the word "capacity" is replaced with different words such as "power" or "jobs". Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, then I think the many responses you've received will get you going in the right direciton. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I will try my best.

Answer (score 0):

Possible he asked about changing CapacityTable property:

```
...
public IQueryable<T> Table
{
    get
    {
        return this.CreateQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use `<pre><code>…` to mark up code; indent the code instead. That way, you won’t have to escape HTML characters.